# int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString()); is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me.

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

This is not working for me. It is showing exception as "Input string was not in a correct format.".

`e.CommandArgument`  is not null, i am getting value for it.

Comment: What's the actual value of `e.CommandArgument`?

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code like below

```
int index;
bool bIsConverted = int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out index);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states the following about `Convert.ToInt32`:

> Converts the specified string representation of a number to an
>   equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

So although your `e.CommandArgument` is not `null`, this doesn't mean it can be converted to a number. You need to check if `e.CommandArgument` contains a value like 1, 20, 42 or something.

If e.CommandArgument could be a number or something else, you can use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This returns a boolean that signals the success of the conversion. It won't throw an exception when the parsing fails.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the spaces

```
   int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString().Trim());
```

IF not check your `e.CommandArgument` value if it is not invalid or `empty`.

Comment: I think you want `.` rather than `,`, and an uppercase `T` wouldn't hurt either.