# GridView Row Command Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` setup with the entity framework with two `TemplateFields` that each call a popup and only displays text from the database. Both `TemplateFields` are setup as `ImageButtons`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvResults" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Soln_SolutionId"  OnRowCommand="grvResults_RowCommand" CssClass="dgstyle" />
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="imgPreview" runat="server" CommandName="viewDoc" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Link")%>' ImageUrl="~/images/viewpage.gif" ImageAlign="Left" Width="25" Height="25" ToolTip="View attachment" AlternateText='<%#Eval("Link")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDetail" runat="server" CommandName="viewDetail" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Soln_SolutionId")%>' ImageUrl="~/images/docview.gif" ImageAlign="Left" Width="25" Height="25" ToolTip="View details about the page" AlternateText="View details" /></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind (C#)

```
protected void grvResults_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int DetailID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            using (VIPCRMEntities dbc = new VIPCRMEntities())
            {
                Solution selDetail = (from c in dbc.Solutions
                                      where c.Soln_SolutionId == DetailID
                                      select c).First();
                if (e.CommandName == "viewDetail")
                {
                    InfoModal.Show();
                    lblInfoText.Text = selDetail.Soln_SolutionDetails;
                }
                else if (e.CommandName == "viewDoc")
                {
                    InfoModal.Show();
                    lblInfoText.Text = selDetail.soln_link;
                }
            }
        }
```

If I click the "viewDetails" image, it works perfectly.
If I click the "viewDoc" image, it fails with the following exception :

**Input string was not in a correct format.** 
  *Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.*

> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a
>   correct format.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 151:         int DetailID =
>   Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

Does any one now why this will happen and how to maybe fix it?

Comment: you should `debug` your code and check the value for `e.CommandArgument` it seems that the value of `e.CommandArgument` is string which is not able to convert into `int` (**i.e it's normal string not number**)

Comment: I have done that. The e.CommandArgument is null, but it works on the other command. I need to know why?

Comment: you used CommandArgument `Link` in first `ImageButton` and you used `Soln_SolutionId` in second `ImageButton `..... it seems you should use `Soln_SolutionId` in first ImageButton also as CommandArgument

Comment: I have tried that as well, it still returns the same exception. I had from the get go the CommandArgument the same. No effect.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

This error states that the value is either null or non nummeric. Attach the debugger an check the value you are receving

Comment: I did that and it returns a null value. The problem is that the one command works fine and the other does not. I need to know why it would do that since it is almost identical code but with different command arguments.

Comment: Does the source data (binded to grid) contain null values?

Comment: There is some null values in the database but the Soln_SolutionId is the primary key of that table and will never be null.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code like below

```
int DetailID;
int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out DetailID);
```

for more refere this link:
[int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString()); is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345332/int-index-convert-toint32e-commandargument-tostring-is-not-working)

Comment: It doesn't even invoke the select command. It gives an error at the declaration of DetailID

Comment: But that is good practices, will put that in before I go to production. Thanks a mill.

Answer (score 0):

It was the logic error on my Row Command. The entity model doesn't like the whole idea of using shared variables in a Gridview Row Command. I'm still readin up on this.

But here is the code that works.

```
if (e.CommandName == "viewDetail")
            {
                int DetailID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                using (VIPCRMEntities dbc = new VIPCRMEntities())
                {
                    Solution selDetail = (from c in dbc.Solutions
                                          where c.Soln_SolutionId == DetailID
                                          select c).First();
                    InfoModal.Show();
                    lblInfoText.Text = selDetail.Soln_SolutionDetails;
                }
            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "viewDoc")
            {
                int DetailID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                using (VIPCRMEntities dbc = new VIPCRMEntities())
                {
                    Solution selDetail = (from c in dbc.Solutions
                                          where c.Soln_SolutionId == DetailID
                                          select c).First();
                    InfoModal.Show();
                    lblInfoText.Text = selDetail.soln_link;
                }               
            }
```